# Sustantivo de "refrescar" as in "rafraichissement" in French

Tags: traducción, informática

Cuando uno presiona la tecla F5 (o manzana + R en un MAC), el navegador refresca la página. Mi pregunta es si existe un sustantivo para este verbo? Existe "refresco" pero suena muy mal.

En inglés no sé tampoco, pero en Francés sería "rafraîchissement de la page".

Os suena algo parecido en Castellano?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque suene mal la palabra sería ***refresco***. 

Refresco se utiliza coloquialmente en el ámbito de las tecnologías de la información.

Lo mismo ocurre en inglés, sería ***refresh***.

Comment: sí? Pero me confirmas que si lo ves escrito en una documentación técnica no te va a sorprender?

Comment: Para mí al menos no. Habitualmente lo utilizamos en el ámbito laboral. Una búsqueda en Google Scholar te puede sacar de dudas.

Comment: Para esclarecer los términos, paso a enumerar los textos que aparecen si nos situamos encima del icono de refresco de los distintos navegadores: en Firefox, Recargar esta página; en Chrome, Cargar página de nuevo; en IExplorer, Actualizar (F5). Pero en ninguno de ellos aparece el sustantivo. En mi respuesta no he incluido el término de "actualización" ya que desde mi punto de vista no indica únicamente cuando refrescamos la página para ver los posibles cambios, sino que indica además cuando el editor de la página la modifica para añadir o eliminar el contenido.

Answer (score 9):

Me parece que el sustantivo más adecuado será :

> **recargo** de la página

que tiene 260 hits<sup>1</sup> en Google seguido por

> **actualización** de la página

que tiene 147 hits y

> **refresco** de la página

que se encuentra 59 veces.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Resultados más relevantes excluyendo entradas muy similares.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

En orden de mejor a peor:

1. El término usado es **actualizar**. No será la traducción apropiada, pero *es* el término que buscas. (Puedes probar con una búsqueda en Google introduciendo `actualizar f5` y la sugerencia inmediata al presionar la tecla de espacio es `actualizar f5 mac`.)
2. *Recargar la página*, es un buena traducción tambień. (respuesta de *ces*)
3. *Refrescar* es la traducción directa. Se entiende.
4. Pero si usas la forma nominal *refresco* de la página, aunque es correcto, la gente tardaría un par de segundos pensando qué querría decir eso.